# possible to change where github pages looks for index.html?

Tags: angularjs, github, yeoman, github-pages

I have a site generated with yeoman's [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) and I'd like to publish this site using github pages. I create the `gh-pages` branch but my repo does not show up in `myusername.github.io/myreponame` I think the reason is because `index.html` is in the `app/` directory not the root.

`app/
  |-- index.html
  |-- scripts/
dist/
Gruntfile.js
etc..`

Can I tell github pages to load index.html from the app folder? How can I launch a site generated w/ angular-generator to gh pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `grunt build` is important as without it `dist` directory is not created. Also changes will appear on gh-pages only after they are added and pushed to the subtree.

1. Remove `dist` from `.gitignore` file
2. Run `grunt build` in console
3. After the project is built the dist directory needs to be added to the GitHub. Run this command in console: `git add dist && git commit -m "Initial dist subtree commit"`
4. And then push the subtree to the gh-pages branch: `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

Answer (score 3):

All of your answers [can be found here](http://yeoman.io/learning/deployment.html)!

In a nutshell, you will generate the deployment-ready version of your site. You do this by running `grunt`. That will generate the optimized, production site in a folder called `dist`. You will then push the contents of `dist` directly to `gh-pages`.

A frequent contributor to Yeoman also made this task: [grunt-build-control](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control), which will let you simply run something like `grunt deploy`.

Comment: any way I can do this without the subtree command? I'm running Ubuntu and don't have `git subtree`