# How can I change my Github Pages default index.html location?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I already tried what's shown on the following threads:

[Can I have my Github Pages index.html in a subfolder of the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320356/can-i-have-my-github-pages-index-html-in-a-subfolder-of-the-repository)

[possible to change where github pages looks for index.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090982/possible-to-change-where-github-pages-looks-for-index-html)

Basically, running `git subtree push --prefix public origin gh-pages` doesn't do anything and I still get a 404 error on my site (located [here](https://github.com/sgarcia-dev/sgarcia-dev.github.io/blob/master/public/index.html)). You can find my site's structure [here](https://github.com/sgarcia-dev/sgarcia-dev.github.io/blob/master/public/index.html).

Here is my Github Pages configuration:
[image]

Also, a possibly important note: my site is being deployed from the **master** branch, not the gh-pages one (it didn't even exist before running the command above)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If what you are asking is how to store the site code in gh-pages instead of master, then you can do this using a repo name that isn't `username.github.io`.

Using `username.github.io` tells GitHub pages that your site code will be in the master branch.

Simply use a normal repository name, and then you will be able to store the code in `gh-pages`.

It shouldn't be an issue for you since you are using a custom domain anyway, but your github.io url would like like `http://username.github.io/repo_name`.

For example, in a normal non `username.github.io` repo, the GitHub settings page will tell you:

> To update your site, push your HTML or Jekyll updates to your gh-pages branch.

This will allow you to run the site off of the gh-pages branch.